# Standard deviation and CLT

Tags: statistics

A random sample of size 24 is taken from a distribution with probability density function:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{9}(x+5/2)$ if $1<x<3$ ($0$ elsewhere).

Let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... X_n$

Approximate $P(48 < S_n < 51.6)$

Clearly, the solution is to use the central limit theorem, such that the probability becomes:

$$P(\frac{48-n\mu}{\sigma \div \sqrt{n}} < Z < \frac{51-n\mu}{\sigma \div \sqrt{n}})$$

I have no problem finding $\mu_{S_n} = 24E(X) = 24\int^{3}_{1}xf(x)dx = 49.7$

However, calculating $\sigma_{S_n} = \sqrt{E(S_n^2)-[E(S_n)]^2}$ is giving me trouble. Specifically, it is unclear to me how to formulate $E(S_n^2)$. How should I do so?

Comment: Why not just compute the variance and take the square root ?? I.e) multiply f(x) by x^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the assumption,you do not have to know the distribution of the $X_i$ to simplify the expression of the variance $S_n$.

Indeed , $S_n$ is the sum of independent and identically distributed variable, therefore, by using respectively the independence and identical feature, we have  $var(S_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{var(X_k)}=nvar(X_1)$

Finally, $var(S_n)=n(E(X_1^2)-E(X_1)^2)$ and $E(X_1^2)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{x^2f(x)dx}$

Comment: Yep, exactly! Nice